# Populating nested underscore templates in Backbone.js

Tags: templates, backbone.js, view, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am attempting to create an html page from a complex JSON object. I have already successfully parsed the JSON object into a Collection of Models, Where each Model has a collection of  another Model etc..

I therefore have nested views to cater for this.

To create my html page, I have two templates like the following:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template1">
        <h1><%=heading1%></h1>
        <h2><%=heading2%></h2>

        <ul id="template2-list"></ul>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id='template2'>
    <p class = "heading"><%-otherheading%></p>

<div class="content" id="tab">

    .....

</div>
</script>
```

As you can see, I have a template (template1) that contains a list of template2. How would I go about populating these templates from my Backbone nested views?

This is what I have tried:

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    type: "CollectionView", //For debugging purposes

    el: "#container", 

    initialize: function () {

    },

    render: function () {
        _.each(this.model.models, this.process, this);
        return this;
    },

    process: function(obj)
    {
        var childItemView = new View1({model: obj});
        childItemView.render();
        this.$el.append(childItemView.el); //This works fine since I only have one Model in the highest level collection
    }

})

var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({

    type: "View1",

    template: _.template($("#template1").html()),

    tagName: "div",
    className: "tableRow",

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.on("change", this.modelChanged, this);
    },

    render: function () {

        var outputHtml = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(outputHtml);

        this.model.get('nestedModel').each(this.process, this);

        return this;
    },

    process: function(obj) {

        var childItemView2 = new View2({model: obj});
        childItemView2.render();   

        childItemView2.el = '#template2-list';

        $(this.el).append(childItemView2.el); //This still results in template2 being placed after the entire template 1

    },

    modelChanged: function(model, changes) {
        console.log("modelChanged: " + this.model.get('title'));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just populating underscore, then you should convert the collection to json(including the submodels collections), and you can add a for loop inside of the template. <% for(var x... %>.

The other option is, to use a library like marionette which has a composite view which can hold collection views, you can see an example for a treeView here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/
it basically shows how to render collections inside collections.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.

Template inside template

Pass the entire collection and do all recursive iteration logic in the template itself by calling the child template inside parent template itself. Only one view is involved.

```
 <script type="text/template" id="template1">
    <h1><%=heading1%></h1>
    <h2><%=heading2%></h2>
    <ul id="template2-list">
       <!-- Your iteration logic goes here -->
       <%= _.template($("#template2").html())({model: model}) %>
    </ul>
 </script>
 <script type="text/template" id='template2'>
     <p class = "heading"><%-otherheading%></p>
     <div class="content" id="tab"></div>
 </script>
```

Better way is:

- In the collection view, create a child view instance(you have done that)
- Do the recursive iteration logic to read the collection models in the collection view(parentview) and call the child view to render the child collections.

If you want a complete solution, create a fiddle with json and html. Will help you to make it work.

Comment: I never thought of doing it the way you did in the first option but would like to try avoid that due to maintainability issues that may arise. With regards to the second option, am I not doing this already? I loop through all of the model's in the parent collection, creating a new child view instance which gets rendered. Since I have a slightly more complex case than this, I do the same within the child view since it to has a collection within its model. I don't see how doing this will allow me to embed what is rendered by the child view within a specific place of the parent view template?

Answer (score 1):

I realised my mistake. Not sure if this is entirely correct, but I rendered the parent view first, then found the new list element (template2-list) and appended the rendered child view to that.

i.e.

```
render: function () {

    var outputHtml = ...

    this.$el.html(outputHtml); //render parent view

    this.model.get('nestedModel').each(this.process, this);

    ...
},

process: function(obj) {

    var childItemView2 = new View2({model: obj});
    childItemView2.render();   

    this.$('#template2-list').append(childItemView2.el); 

},
```

Thanks for all the help!